# Saving array in mysql using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this form where I have one select list and two textboxex which can be dynamically added to form multiple rows. The scenario is that I will have one select value and multiple textbox values. I want to save this is mysql table which has three columns: SelectValue, TextBox1Value and TextBox2Value.  SelectValue will be same/duplicate but textbox values should be  unique.
I have tried following php:

```
include('connection.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $roomId = $_POST['roomno'];

    $rowData = array();
    foreach($_POST['inventoryname'] as $row=>$inventory){
        $inventoryName = mysql_real_escape_string($inventory);
        $inventoryCount = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inventorycount'][$row]);

        $rowData[] = "('$inventoryName','$inventoryCount')"; 
    }
}
if(!empty($rowData)){
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO room_inventory_details(RoomId,Inventory,Count) VALUES('$roomId')".implode(',',$rowData));

    if(!$insert){
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }else{
        echo "Data saved successfullt";
    }
}
```

And here is my markup

```
<form action="save_room_inventory.php" method="post" name="reservation-form" id="reservation_form">
    <div class="left-form">
        <label for="roomno"><span>Room No.</span>
            <select name="roomno">
                <option value="">---Please Select---</option>
                <?php
                    include('connection.php');
                    $select_query = mysql_query("SELECT RoomId,RoomName FROM room ORDER BY RoomName");
                    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_query)){ ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $rows['RoomId']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['RoomName']?></option>
                <?php   }
                ?>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="left-form">
        <input type="button" id="addinventory" Value="Add Inventory">
    </div>
    <div class="inventory-table">
        <div class="detail-table">
            <table class="itemTable" border="1">
                <thead>
                    <th>Inventory</th>
                    <th>Count</th>
                    <th><input type="button" value="Add New Row" id="addNew"></th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="cloneme">
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="inventoryname[]">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="inventorycount[]">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event_button">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
        <input type="reset" name="reset" Value="Clear">
        <iframe name="acknowledgement" id="res_frame"></iframe>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am having the following error when I save:
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('Bed','1'),('Cderf','4')' at line 1

Comment: I don't seem to see anything close to `('Bed','1'),('Cderf','4')` in the queries you showed.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek It comes from `implode(',', $rowData)`.

Comment: People, if you're coding with database applications it's literally your job to make sure you are using the correct, most updated functions to prevent injection attacks.  Double check with your mysql functions to ensure that they are not depreciated.  **mysql_query** IS DEPRECIATED and poses direct injection vulnerabilities.  Please use **prepared statements** when working with database connections in PHP.  If you're not sure what a prepared statement is, please research and read up on it, it will save you and future developers who work with your code a lot of trouble.

Comment: @Axel Wouldn't it be easier to switch to `mysqli`? Would be much less changing in the code.

Comment: [mysqli supports prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), so yes...that is a solution.

Comment: @Alex I understand your concerns. But I am not building a website here. I am just building a small system for a local customer who will use it in his local machine.

Comment: That may be so, however you are being paid to provide code to a customer.  At the very least you can ensure the functions you use aren't depreciated.  If your customer decides to upgrade to a newer version of PHP that removes the depreciated functions (which can very well happen), your entire code becomes useless.  I'm just saying, you're being paid for professional coding, just because it's only running on a local machine doesn't make it okay to half-ass it.  I'm not trying to nit-pick or come off as an ass, I just feel that all code should be written to the best standard possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one value in `VALUES ('$roomId')`, and only two values in each of `$rowData`. You need 3 values in all of them. Do that by putting `$roomId` into each of the elements in the `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($_POST['inventoryname'] as $row=>$inventory){
    $inventoryName = mysql_real_escape_string($inventory);
    $inventoryCount = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inventorycount'][$row]);

    $rowData[] = "('$roomId', '$inventoryName','$inventoryCount')"; 
}
```

Then your `INSERT` should be:

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO room_inventory_details(RoomId,Inventory,Count) VALUES ".implode(',',$rowData));
```

BTW, you should use `mysql_real_escape_string` when assigning `$roomId`, too.